# PHP web framework similar to Django

Tags: web-development, php, framework

I'm looking for a PHP web framework that has functionality similar to [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/). These are the most important requirements that come to mind:

- [ORM features](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/) providing a universal way to manipulate data rows as objects regardless of database backend
- A way to write your [data models in code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/), which are then used to [generate migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/writing-migrations/) that will perform scheme-altering operations on your database
- A [generic admin tool](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/) that can easily be extended to quickly build a CRUD tool for your models
- A seperation between views and templates, the latter having a powerful [template engine](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/language/)

Answer (score 1):

I think Laravel meet your requirement.

1. **ORM**

   Laravel has it's own ORM, called [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent).
2. **Models & Migrations**

   If we refer to Model, mostly (laravel) developer refer eloquent [as a model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#defining-models). And this is for laravel [migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations).
3. **Generic Admin Tool**

   Actually, laravel does not have capabilities for this, but there is a package for that. [Backpack for Laravel](https://backpackforlaravel.com/) or [Voyager](https://the-control-group.github.io/voyager/). See voyager [in action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_gp4E7tC-Vs).
4. **Template Engine**

   Laravel has [Blade Template Engine](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade).